# Cannot Upload new file to Azure.Storage.Blob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

currently I am trying to upload my files to Azure Storage using `Azure.Storage.Blobs`. I have correctly initalize a BlobContainerClient using the connection string and container name, however at the moment when I try to initialize a BlobClient using `GetBlobClient(filepath)`, for example:

```
GetBlobClient('./data/image.png')
```

I need to have a file exist in `./data/image.png` for the program to pick up and overwrite this file as I upload my file by overwriting. And if I just change file path to the same directory but with different file name (i.e change `image.png` -> `newimage.png`) then file BlobClient does not exist.

Can I ask how to upload new file to the Azure Storage Container? Is this something related to container permission or something else?

Thank you so much.

Here is my current code:

```
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
try
   {
    //Require a "file" exist before hand, or else the client does not exist
    BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(filepath);
    if (blobClient.Exists())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("BlobClient exist!");
      var stream = File.OpenRead("image.png")
      blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, overwrite: true);
      succeeded = true;
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("BlobClient does not exist");
      succeeded = false;
    }
      
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  throw new Exception(e);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. Are you asking how to upload a file and save as a new blob (essentially `else` block of your code)?

Comment: Ah sorry I figured things out, so it wasn't that I need to have the file exist or not, but what I need is to set permission to be able to write on the BobClient. In which what I did is using `SetAccessPolicy(PublicAccessType.Blob)`. I was caught of guard because when there is no file in the given directory the function doesn't allow me to just upload new files in, and if there is existing file the function still let me upload new file by overwritting existing file with same name

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot Upload new file to Azure.Storage.Blob?

You can upload a file using that.

> Can I ask how to upload new file to the Azure Storage Container?

I have reproduced in my environment to upload files when a file is present in directory, if not it gives error as message and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet):

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

Console.WriteLine("Hello Rithwik running your code!!!");
Console.WriteLine("**************");
Console.WriteLine("**************");
string cs = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik;AccountKey=pPBW9kA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
string cn = "rithwik1";
BlobContainerClient bcc = new BlobContainerClient(cs, cn);

try
{
    string fp = @"C:\Users\Downloads\Rith.png"; 
    string bn = "image.png"; 

    BlobClient bc = bcc.GetBlobClient(bn);

    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fp))
    {
        await bc.UploadAsync(fileStream, overwrite: true);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"File uploaded successfully into conatiner : {cn} .");
    Console.WriteLine("**************");
    Console.WriteLine("**************");
    Console.WriteLine("Thank You");
}
catch (Exception e)
{

    Console.WriteLine($"Error has detected in the above code : {e.Message}");
    Console.WriteLine("**************");
    Console.WriteLine("**************");
    Console.WriteLine("Please do the needful");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

[image]

cn is container name

cs is connection string

fp is filepath

**Output:**

If file present in directory(it overwrites too) :

[image]

[image]

If file is not present in directory:

[image]